# Check radio button on button click inside the label

Tags: javascript, html

Clicking on label checks the radio button but not on click of a button inside that label

Check the example

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gu55B/299/)

```
<input id="349" type="radio" value="1" name="question1">
<label for="349"><button type="button">  Abe   </button></label>
<br>
<input id="350" type="radio" value="2" name="question1">
<label for="350">Andrew</label>
```

Comment: Why would you put a button inside a checkbox's label? (You could try using a click event listener on the button and setting the radio checked from there. Two lines of JS. But again, why?)

Comment: `<button>` element is not intended to do that, it has its own click event resolver. At the same time `<label>` element was provided for focusing on the input elements. You should use it and style appropriately.

Comment: I think you are trying to give additional options on a button click or something, whatever it is, this design is wrong. If you insist on it, then you have to manually code the radio button from the button's click handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an *onclick* event to the button in question and link it to the input radio tag.

```
function abe() {
  $('#349').trigger('click');
}
```

Here is a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r2masf5t/

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of jQuery you can do this.

```
$('form').on('click', 'button', function() {
  $(this).closest('label').prev('input').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/56c1zd6b/

Answer (score 0):

You should add an id to the button, like this for example:

```
<button id="btn_349" type="button">
    Abe
</button>
```

then play with some jQuery:

```
$("#btn_349").on("click", function(){
    $("#349").prop("checked", true);
});
```

or if for some reason you want pure js, then use this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn_349");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("349").checked = true;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value by checking which radio button is checked and also get value of label by checking the `for` attribute value

```
<button type="button" onclick="GetName()">Abe</button>
function GetName()
{

  var value = $("input[name='question1']:checked").val();
  var name = $('label[for=' + $("input[name='question1']:checked").attr("id") + ']').text();
}
```